# Winjs not working in multi-device hybrid app

Tags: winjs, visual-studio-cordova

I 'm using WinJS in multi-device-hybrid app template in one of my page .But the code is not working fine (below is code).

```
      HTML
      <a id="facebook">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
        </a>



  Javascript-
 ready: function (element, options) {
        // TODO: Initialize the page here.
        document.getElementById("facebook").onclick = function () {
            if (checkconnection())
                document.getElementById("facebook").href = "https://www.facebook.com/amit.porwal.14";
            else
                Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Check your Network Connection").showAsync();
        }

        function checkconnection() {
            var connectivity = Windows.Networking.Connectivity;
            var profile = connectivity.NetworkInformation.getInternetConnectionProfile();
            if (profile) {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
```

when i 'm  not using checkconnection() function the app is working fine with navigation to the facebook website.
So is there any restriction on using  winjs in multi-device-hybrid template .
I 'm debuging this on android device.

With that i 'm also using

```
    Wins.xhr ,<x-ms-webview>
```

in my app but none of them is working .

Answer (score 2):

Any API's that begin with Windows.* is a WinRT API and are *not* part of WinJS. WinJS APIs always start with WinJS.*; the Windows.* APIs work only on Windows/Windows Phone 8/8.1 and won't work on Android.

WinJS.xhr is just a simple wrapper for XMLHttpRequest, so should work on any system with the DOM API available. You typed Wins.xhr, however, so maybe you just have a typo.

As for , that also is an HTML element specific to the Windows app host, and isn't part of the standard DOM. If you're targeting Android you'll need to use its HTML Webview equivalent.

Comment: @ Kraig - Thanks for your response . Can U please elucidate the procedure to do that with example.I mean to say where to write the extra code.

Comment: @ Kraig - consider me as a novice .

Comment: Unfortunately I don't as yet know the Android API equivalents. I'm merely pointing out that WinJS (WinJS.* namespace) is it's own library that can be used across platforms, but the WinRT (Windows.*) API is exclusive to Windows, as is x-ms-Webview. The code you show above using Windows.Networking.Connectivity will work only on Windows, same with Windows.UI.Popups. That's why there are solutions like Cordova/PhoneGap that have you write to a generic wrapper API that's then translated appropriately to the target OS.

Comment: @ Kraig - Howdy.... I 'm back here to boggle your mind with my silly  question .It will be very helpful to me  if you show your interest in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613012/how-to-make-two-winjs-xhr-call-one-for-retrieving-the-captca-from-a-website-and)

Comment: @ Kraig - Just steer me in the right direction rest i will do it myself .

Comment: I responded to your other post.