# How to make two Winjs.xhr call one for retrieving the Captca from a website and another to submit data back

Tags: javascript, windows, html, winjs

I 'm making a windows app using HTML5/JAVASCRIPT . What actually i want is to retrieve a captcha from a website  and then submitting the captcha along with other  form field to the website(.aspx) back and getting the response back.I think that i have to handle cookies for this purpose ,but i do not know how to do this .
100 times salute to the person who will show interest in this . 
Here is what i did .

```
             //  Retrieving  the Captcha.   
            WinJS.xhr({
            url: "http://example.in/main.aspx",
            type: "get",
            responseType: "document",
            headers: {
                "CONTENT-TYPE": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",

                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; MSAppHost/2.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
                "CONNECTION": "keep-alive",
                },
            }).then(
                function complete(xhr) {
                    var image = document.createElement("img");
                    image.src = xhr.response.querySelector("img[alt='Captcha']").src;
                  document.getElementById("captcha").appendChild(image);

                });


        //submit the data ..

        document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function () {
            WinJS.xhr({
                url: "http://example.in/main.aspx/",
                type: "post",
                responsetype: "document",
                headers: {
                    "CONTENT-TYPE": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; MSAppHost/2.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
                     "CONNECTION" : "keep-alive",
                    },
                data: alldata       // all data contain username,password and captcha(entered by user) 

            }).then(
                   function complete(xhr) {
                           document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = toStaticHTML(xhr.response);
                     });
```

I know that here i have to handle cookie , but really no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WinJS.xhr API is just a wrapper for the HTML XMLHttpRequest API, which unfortunately doesn't let you get to cookies and such.

You'll thus need to use the [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) API instead, which does allow you access to cookies and everything else.

Start with the [Windows.Web.Http landing page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.aspx) for an overview, followed by [How to connect to an HTTP Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn469430.aspx) for the next level of details. Refer also to the [HttpClient sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664), specifically scnearios 8, 9, and 10 that deal with cookies.

I also cover the details of this API (and making HTTP requests in general) in Chapter 4 of my free ebook, [*Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, 2nd Edition*](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2).

That should get you going.

Comment: @ Kraig - Howdy....I 'm very happy to see you here .Actually i want to target my app for all  platform .So Unfortunately Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient won't work over here.

Comment: You'll likely then need to write some platform-specific code for this area. XMLHttpRequest (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest for generic docs) doesn't provide much control over cookies, which is one reason why the HttpClient API was added on Windows. If you're targeting cross-platform, you might look into Apache Cordova as a toolset--it might have some solutions for this sort of thing, but I'm not yet familiar with Cordova enough to know.

Comment: @ kraig Brockschmidt - Howdy ....one last question ..Is there any way to bind the session in xhr call .I mean to say if somehow we bind the two winjs.xhr call (see in above code ) with the ASP.NET_sessionID  then we can achieve what we want ???? .....

Comment: I don't know offhand, but I believe it's something you look at on the server side. WinJS.xhr just uses XMLHttpRequest underneath, and if there's a session cookie I think it picks it up. I haven't worked with this directly, however, so I could be wrong. I suggest, then, that you investigate sessions and XMLHttpRequest, which should give you insights here.